# Export data from database into C# statements

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-5

I'm writing up a set of unit-tests for my MVC4 application. I want to create a test-database that would be dropped and re-populated before every test. 
For that I need a seed function that would do something like this:

```
var project = new Project() {Name = "Project One", Description = "Watermelons make you high!"}
_context.Projects.Add(project);

var projectTwo = new Project() {Name = "Project Two", Description = "Insert your joke here"}
_context.Projects.Add(project);
```

and so on, for all the objects I'm going to test against. The more - the better.

And I'm lazy. I don't want to write all of this in C# myself. But I can use web-app I've developed to quickly create a lot of test data.

Now the **question is how to convert data in the database (sql server 2012) into C# statements**, like example above?

I can export database as a sql statement and run it every time for every script. But whenever my model changes (like new fields), I will need to re-create the sql. Also sometimes it would be good to be able to access the objects as they have been put into DB, and sql script would not allow for that.

Another option is to whip up a few regular expressions to convert sql-script into objects. Not sure how much work that is. <strike>I'll probably end up doing this at the end.</strike>

So, are there any tools available that can translate data in the database into C# objects?

Comment: From my understanding you have a test database that you want to take data from and load into the _context. Why can't you connect the test database up and use entityframework to cycle though the database and load the _context up?

Comment: That is the problem: there is no data anywhere. I'll need to create it. And instead of writing c# statements, I want to use interface, and then convert created data into c#. I'll be dropping that DB for every test. So that must be c# statements so I can re-create the db again.

Comment: I am a bit confused now. Can you please tell me what is this web-app that creates data do. When you create data to put into a database is it in sql statments? Does it go straight into a database? Or what?

Comment: yes, data goes into db via EF. But I'm working on tests now. For tests I need to programmatically re-create database and all the data there. Connecting to other databases is not an option here.

Comment: Have you thought about creating a compact sql database for your units tests then. So you have the compact sql database in your solution you can load it and unload it up with data and access it from the unit tests. Here is a link with someone setting up a compact sql database to test nhibernate http://slynetblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/setup-sql-server-compact-4-to-unit-test.html

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing. But I need data there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15829/discussion-between-kingpancake-and-trailmax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a for loop to run say 100 times. And in there have it create a new project and add it to the _context like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    _context.Projects.Add(new Project() {Name = string.format("Name{0}", i), Description = string.format("Description{0}", i) });
}
```

And like you suggested in that chat, get a dictinary of random words to put in place of name and description to get random data every time.

Comment: Yep - simple and effective. Why did I not think of this myself - I don't know. Probably lack of sleep does not help -)